# How to calculate the length of a line that comes out of a vertex of a rhomboid?

Tags: geometry

[Romboide del ejercicio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8JVY.png)

$\overline{PM}\quad=2 m$

$\overline{MN}\quad=16 m$

*Find* $\overline{AP}\quad$

*Alternatives*

a) $6$

b) $6.5$

c) $7$

d) $7.5$

e) $6.55$

Hello, the subject of the exercise in metric relationships in a triangle.

I could find that the triangle $ ABM $ is congruent with the triangle $ MNC $, and that the prolongation of  $\overline{AB}\quad$ up to the imaginary straight line where the point $ N $ is, would form a triangle that is equal to the $ DNA $ triangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This involves selecting an answer that yields a consistent proportionality between three pairs of similar triangles. That is, triangles $ABM$ and $NCM$, and triangles $ABP$ and $NDP$, and triangles $BPM$ and $APD$ are all similar pairs. These similarities result from vertical and alternate angles associated with the parallel lines of the rhombus.

The only answer that maintains the proportions of the three pairs of similar triangles is answer (a) which is $6$.

If $AP = 6$, then $AM = 8$ and with $MN = 16$, the proportion of similar triangles $ABM$ and $NMC$ is $1:2$. If $BM = x$, then$ MC = 2x$. Therefore $AB$ and $DC = 3x$ and $CN = 6x$ in keeping with the $1:2$ ratio.

When we look at triangles $ABP$ and $NDP$, $AB = 3x$ and $DN = 9x$, so we have a $1:3$ ratio with these two similar triangles. Maintaining the $1:3$ ratio, $AP = 6$ and $PN = 18$, and $BP = \frac{1}{3}PD$ which are also corresponding sides of the third pair of similar triangles $BPM$ and $APD$ where $BM = x$ and $AD = 3x$, and $PM = 2$ and $AP = 6$ thus maintaining the $1:3$ ratio.

Other answers don't maintain a consistent ratio. There may be a different and better solution method but I couldn't see one.

[image]